# Is there any way to know that weather a file completely send from server to client?

Tags: php, laravel

Actually want to run a query to update database when the server completely 
    send the downloading file or client have completely downloaded the file.If 
    file is not downloaded or canceled by the client then database remain 
    unchanged. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: for your issue you need to call other ajax to update db because your purpose is to first download the file and update the db.

Comment: But for me issue is how to know file is downloaded??

Comment: it will be return on error:  part of ajax as @ratnesh answared below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax if query run successfully then success msg if fails the fauilure msg

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your /route/url",
    data: data,
    success: function() {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('failure');
    }
})
```

Comment: there is no issue to run query, what exactly problem to know that file is downloaded by client